# Uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reason: 'Receiver .. has no segue'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just started recently. I can't fix it and I don't know How to do

I have attached files and images. When I run my app, I receive the following error:

```
        2015-11-26 12:17:08.175 login[6107:324531] 
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Receiver (<login.ViewController: 0x7fc0d94b28d0>) 
has no segue with identifier 'loginView''

        *** First throw call stack:

        (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100457f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010217bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48

            2   UIKit                               0x0000000100e099ea -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0

            3   login                               0x000000010025fc85 _TFC5login14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 309

            4   login                               0x000000010025fce1 _TToFC5login14ViewController13viewDidAppearfS0_FSbT_ + 49

            5   UIKit                               0x0000000100e0c675 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 830

            6   UIKit                               0x0000000100e0cff8 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 262

            7   UIKit                               0x0000000100e47a00 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1290

            8   UIKit                               0x0000000100e3d917 __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 233

            9   UIKit                               0x000000010166db24 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 101

            10  UIKit                               0x0000000100c5cf4a __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke93 + 834

            11  UIKit                               0x0000000100d1eace -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 644

            12  UIKit                               0x0000000100cfc9df -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 241

            13  UIKit                               0x0000000100cfcd8e -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80

            14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001051b9fa0 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308

            15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102c4f49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8

            16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102c372af _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738

            17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003b82e9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9

            18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001003798a9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073

            19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100378e08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488

            20  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104a4bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161

            21  UIKit                               0x0000000100c7430d UIApplicationMain + 171

            22  login                               0x00000001002630dd main + 109

            23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000102c8392d start + 1

        )

        libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My screenshots of code are here:

[Screenshots of code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8t22khw50ispj8o/AAAdObkEpA3qkikrn2XBWepsa?dl=0)

Comment: how do you call the performsegue can you show your code once'

Answer (score 0):

Your error tells you exactly what you need to do.

`Receiver (<login.ViewController: 0x7fc0d94b28d0>) has no segue with identifier 'loginView'`

so check your segue in storyboard and ensure that segue identifier from `LoginViewController` is `loginView`.